# How to check for external connections to my firebase real-time database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I created a firebase project which is connected to my custom domain (my live website).

I hired a developer to build features for my website which I deploy myself when he passes the code to me.
To do this, the developer needed access to my project's real-time database to test the features on their test website built on netlify.

However the issue is, everytime users enter feedback or data on my live website, the data is written to the firebase real-time database AND at the same time the developers website (I tested this).

This is a real security concern because it means that user data is not secured & private as per GPDR.

**question**
Is there a way to check for and remove all external connections to a firebase real-time database?

**potential solution**
The only other solution I can think of is creating a new project, disconnecting my domain from the current project and re-connecting it to the new project. At least this way, any new data created from users interacting with my website will be added to the new project's database rather than the old one.

Appreciate your thoughts on the question and the potential solution
J

**things tried**

1. I removed excess permissions to my database for the developer (downgrading them to an analytics viewer role only)
2. I removed excess permissions on google cloud for service accounts that had access to the real-time database

**things I am going to try**

1. I just consulted someone on fiverr and they recommend changing the API key to remove access
2. They also recommend reviewing the security rules to ensure there are no vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there is no such way to find external connections to your firebase database. But all users that are accessing your database by blocking the Api-key in firebase project and creating a new one for you.

Steps you can follow to block Api key are:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/.
2. Select your firebase project from top.
3. Search credentials in the search box.
4. In API keys section you will find your firebase API key. Click on it
   5.At the top you will find the option to delete the API key

[Fourth Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyd89.png)
[Fifth Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPk6t.png)