# How can I change the real-time database for my web app to a new firebase project?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**background**

I had a web app created for me on firebase and this project is connected to my domain.

When users visit the domain/website they input data and this data gets saved to the realtime database.

Because of security concerns as my realtime database is already compromised, see link for this: [How to check for external connections to my firebase real-time database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75634263/how-to-check-for-external-connections-to-my-firebase-real-time-database)

I wanted to have two environments, one for testing and one for production. So I created a new firebase project to become my production project leaving the old one as the test project.

I disconnected the domain from the old project and connected to the new one.

**problem**

When users are interacting with my website, the data is still being sent to the compromised realtime database of the old project rather than the new project.

NOTE: My app has been written in Angular

What I tried.

1. I looked through the html and src files for my web app to see where the firebase configs were listed.
2. Inside the src\app folder I found 3 files written in typescript that had firebase config references
3. I replaced these config references with the configs from my new project (see below example config text)
4. I then redeployed this code to host on my new firebase project

Config text example from point 3 above

```
const firebaseConfig = 
{  
  apiKey: "API key xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "websitexxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",  
  databaseURL: "https://websitexxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe- 
 west1.firebasedatabase.app",
  projectId: "websitexxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "websitexxxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "00000000000",
  appId: "1:0000000:web:xyxyxyxyxyx",
  measurementId: "G-xyxyxyx"
};
```

Would appreciate your help as I am stumped and not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok answering my question as its been a nightmare trying to resolve this and it took consulting on fiverr.

The root cause of the problem is the config files were not overwritten correctly. Here's how to do this if you ever get the same issue.

Step 1. open your project code using visual studio code

Step 2. use Ctrl + Shift + f to use the address bar function for Visual studio

Step 3. type "API key" in the search bar to find all the files that reference "API" because these will contain the config text you need to replace

Step 4. ensure you overwrite the old web API configs in all these files with the API configs from the new project

Step 5. delete the dist folder of the project and before you deploy go to the command line terminal and type "ng build" to recreate this dist folder

Step 6. redeploy your project (assuming you know how to deploy on firebase deploy)

Voila, when you interact and add data to your new project's domain/website you'll notice it gets written to the new project's realtime database rather than the old one